# How to fix smooth navigation fixed in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hello I have this smooth scrolling navigation fixed when user's scroll down to the site.. But when the page go up and removes the class `nav_fixed` the header part jumps through it.. How do I tweak my jquery code that also enables smooth scrolling of the header part when user scrolls up.. As you can see in the sample below the behavior of the header jumps and it's kind of a minor bug.

```js
/* Fixed Header Parallax */
  var header_height = $('header').outerHeight(); //number of pixels before modifying styles

  $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > header_height) {
      $('header').addClass('nav_fixed');
      $('.dummyHeight').addClass('addHeight');
    } else {
      $('header').removeClass('nav_fixed');
      $('.dummyHeight').removeClass('addHeight');
    }
  });
```

```css
.main {height:700px;}
.addHeight {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
/* Header */
header {
  background: red;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #caccd0;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.nav_fixed {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 45;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  animation-name: fade-in;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
@keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.addHeight {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #232323;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 67px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>

    Sample

    <div id="nav_area">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="dummyHeight"></div>

<div class="main">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this what you need? Let me know if you need something else. I have modified script to remove that jump you are telling. I have removed the classes when you reach header scrolling up all the way.

```js
/* Fixed Header Parallax */
  var header_height = $('header').outerHeight(); //number of pixels before modifying styles
  var offset = $('header').offset();
  
  $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
  
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > header_height) {
      $('header').addClass('nav_fixed');
      $('.dummyHeight').addClass('addHeight');
    } else if(scrollTop == offset.top) {
      $('header').removeClass('nav_fixed');
      $('.dummyHeight').removeClass('addHeight');
    }
  });
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
.main {height:700px;}
.addHeight {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
/* Header */
header {
  background: red;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #caccd0;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.nav_fixed {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 45;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  animation-name: fade-in;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
@keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.addHeight {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #232323;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 67px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


<header>

    Sample

    <div id="nav_area">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="dummyHeight"></div>

<div class="main">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! this is what I exactly needed. Thank you so much. <3

Comment: Glad! It helped.